# Sed command for performance improvement or tr command for the same

Tags: text-processing, sed, tr

I have a command to replace the non printable characters and single quotes from a file but its taking more time to execute as I am replacing these characters for multiple files and the files size is around 30GB.

```
LANG=iso-8859-1 sed -i 's/[^[:print:]]//g;s/'\''//g;s/&apos;//g' $path/EID*_$1.xml
```

The `$path` and `$1` passing through parameters. How can I make the process run faster and is there any other command which I can use? I heard `tr` command is faster compare to `sed` but how can I use the `tr` command in my situation. (`tr` command in single line for all the files).

I tried this command:

```
LANG=iso-8859-1 sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g;s/'\''//g;s/&apos;//g' < $path/EID123_$1.xml > $path/EID123_$1_new.xml
mv -f $path/EID123_$1_new.xml EID123_$1.xml
LANG=iso-8859-1 sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g;s/'\''//g;s/&apos;//g' <     $path/EID456_$1.xml > $path/EID456_$1_new.xml;
mv -f $path/EID456_$1_new.xml EID456_$1.xml
```

for each single files without i option but its not giving the expected result and I could still see the non printable characters in file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include i) an example of your file; ii) the output you would like from that example and iii) an explanation of exactly what characters you want to remove. What is `&apos;` supposed to be, for example?

Comment: Without knowing the details I can't say for sure, but doing a for loop that forks itself into several background processes might increase your sed performance by a great deal, there is an answer about it here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103920/parallelize-a-bash-for-loop

Comment: would the `strings` command work for you?

Comment: for one you do not need to the mv part, just use sed -i option it will do it for you.

Comment: @terdon, My file is of xml file and &apos;  determines the single quotes. so I want to get rid of single quotes(') and &apos; from the file and also I want to remove all the non printable characters([^[:print:]]) from file. The above command works fine but just that its taking time.

Comment: @Rob, in the -i option the sed command usually takes more time to execute thats why I was trying to remove -i and was using mv command at the end

Comment: Can we use  tr command to do the same thing?

Comment: @Azhar please *[edit]* your question and give us an example of your input and desired output as I requested. That way, we can know exactly what you need. Make sure to include examples of all the characters/strings you want to remove. Note, however, that if you want to modify several files of ~30GB size, it will be slow no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Input binary file **foo**, and for any character that's not printable (or some kind of space), replace that char with a space, and send output to pipe, where another **tr** replaces single quotes with spaces, then output that to **bar**.

```
tr --complement '[:print:]'  ' ' < foo | tr "'"  ' ' > bar
```