# Concurrency of a find, hash val, and replace across large amount of rows

Tags: sed, hashsum, concurrency

I have a bunch of files and for each row there is a unique value I'm trying to obscure with a hash.

However there are 3M rows across the files and a rough calculation of the time needed to complete the process is hilariously long at 32days.

```
for y in files*; do 
  cat $y | while read z; do
    KEY=$(echo $z | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr -d '"')
    HASH=$(echo $KEY | sha1sum | awk '{ print $1 }')
    sed -i -e "s/$KEY/$HASH/g" $y
  done
done
```

To improve this processes speed I assume I'm going to have to introduce some concurrency.

A hasty attempt based of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475 led me to

```
N=4
(
for y in gta*; do 
  cat $y | while read z; do
    (i=i%N)); ((i++==0)); wait
    ((GTA=$(echo $z | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr -d '"')
    HASH=$(echo $GTA | sha1sum | awk '{ print $1 }')
    sed -i -e "s/$KEY/$HASH/g) & 
  done
done
)
```

Which performs no better.

Example input

```
"2000000000" : ["200000", "2000000000"]
"2000000001" : ["200000", "2000000001"]
```

Example output

```
"e8bb6adbb44a2f4c795da6986c8f008d05938fac" : ["200000", "e8bb6adbb44a2f4c795da6986c8f008d05938fac"]
"aaac41fe0491d5855591b849453a58c206d424df" : ["200000", "aaac41fe0491d5855591b849453a58c206d424df"]
```

Perhaps I should read the lines concurrently then perform the hash-replace on each line?

Comment: Please include an example input with very few lines and the output you expect. Currenty, this code will be very inefficient for many lines, because it contains many process calls, around 10 per line. Also the shell is not suitable to read large files line by line. To be perfomant, you have to call one program to process the whole file.

Comment: @thanasisp I can give an example of the input/output. I see no way around using these many calls per line. Unless I were to create an intermediary file. Which of course I can do as an experiment at least. But I think only expensive call out of all of those is `sha1sum`.

Comment: I believe this `sed -i` takes almost all of the time, but after some small reproducible testable exampe, the whole process can be improved.

Comment: The major fault in your process (first attempt) is that sed is happily overwriting the current file while cat is still reading it, and sending some unknown amount of it into a pipe. The second version has an unbalanced quote and does not name the file it is editing. Nobody doubts that this would run for 32 days: it creates at least 20 million processes and rewrites a file 3 million times. Shell is so much the wrong tool for this. Last time I saw a script like this, I got the runtime down from 30 days to 2 minutes using awk.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the problem is that, while we should be able to improve the performance, having to call sha1sum once per line WILL be a major bottleneck in this case since calling it from awk would require creating a subshell every time awk reads a line. If there's a tool out there with `sha1sum` functionality built in (perl? python?) that'd be a much better approach wrt execution speed.

Comment: @αғsнιη please reread my Example `"2000000001" : ["200000", "2000000000"]` was my fat fingered mistake. The input line should have actually been "2000000001" : ["200000", "2000000001"].

Comment: @EdMorton I'm verifying my own solution within Python. Almost there!

Comment: @EdMorton Standard sha1sum is a single-shot tool. I just timed it for 10,000 12-digit numbers, got 2m44s. That scales to 6 days for 30 million values. If this was my team's project, I would have somebody writing a bulk version by now. I can see python3 can import hashlib, and the example in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sha-in-python gives the same result as GNU sha1sum. Back on solid ground, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW I think this is the fastest way you could do it in a shell script:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in "$@"; do
    while IFS='"' read -ra a; do
        sha=$(printf '%s' "${a[1]}" | sha1sum)
        sha="${sha% *}"
        printf '%s"%s"%s"%s"%s"%s"%s"\n' "${a[0]}" "$sha" "${a[2]}" "${a[3]}" "${a[4]}" "$sha" "${a[6]}"
    done < "$file"
done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
```

```
$ cat file
"e8bb6adbb44a2f4c795da6986c8f008d05938fac" : ["200000", "e8bb6adbb44a2f4c795da6986c8f008d05938fac"]"
"aaac41fe0491d5855591b849453a58c206d424df" : ["200000", "aaac41fe0491d5855591b849453a58c206d424df"]"
```

but as I mentioned in the comments you'd be better of for speed of execution using a tool with sha1sum functionality built in, e.g. python.

Comment: As this solves the original question. And @EdMorton was first (out of people who posted  a solution) to suggest the solution I actually used, Python. I'm picking this answer.

Comment: I'll stick to suggestions next time.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille thank you for the effort. Sadly I can't pick two answers :(

Comment: no worries, as the ozzies say.

Answer (score 3):

As advised by Ed Morton, with a little help from python.

Create a python script /tmp/sha1.py and make it executable

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python -u

import hashlib
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
  words = line.split()
  str_hash=hashlib.sha1(words[0].encode())
  words[0] = str_hash.hexdigest()
  print(" ".join(words))
```

The first line should contain the correct location of your python, but don't remove the "-u".

Then a ksh script, that you should also make executable.

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

/tmp/sha1.py |&

for y in files*
do
  while read A B
  do
    eval "echo $A" >&p
    read A <&p
    echo \"$A\" $B
  done < $y > TMP.$y
  mv TMP.$y $y
done

# terminate sha1.py
exec 3>&p
exec 3>&-
```

Now, if you want performance, you should let python handle a complete file at once.  The following scripts treats each input line as a filename, and does your dirty work:

```
#! /usr/local/bin/python

import hashlib
import os
import sys

for IFileNmX in sys.stdin:
  IFileNm = IFileNmX.strip()
  IFile = open(IFileNm,'r')
  OFileNm = ".".join(["TMP",IFileNm])
  OFile = open(OFileNm,'w')
  for line in IFile.readlines():
    words = line.split()
    word1 = words[0].strip('"')
    str_hash=hashlib.sha1(word1.encode())
    words[0] = "".join(['"',str_hash.hexdigest(),'"'])
    OFile.write("".join([" ".join(words),'\n']))
  OFile.close()
  IFile.close()
  os.rename(OFileNm,IFileNm)
```

If you call this script /tmp/sha1f.py, and make it executable, I wonder how many minutes

```
ls files* | /tmp/sha1f.py
```

would take.  My system took 12 seconds to deal with a 400Mb file of a million lines.  But that's boasting, of course.

Comment: Thank you this informed me on my solution.

Comment: You can use `os.listdir` function to get file list in python and `multiprocessing` module, shipped in python standard library to process several files in parallel.