# Limit background number of jobs in for loop

Tags: shell-script

I have a very simple script, that will remux all files in all subfolders to `mkv`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Works with subfolders too

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nocaseglob
shopt -s globstar


for file in "${1%/}/"**/*(*.mp4|*.avi); do

mkvmerge -v -M -B --no-chapters --disable-language-ietf --engage no_cue_duration --engage no_cue_relative_position --clusters-in-meta-seek --disable-lacing --engage no_simpleblocks "$file" -o "${file%.*}".mkv &

done
```

How can I limit the background jobs to batches of 300 ? Meaning I'd like to run this command in batches of 300 files, and wait for them to finish/wait X time and start a new batch

Comment: there are several answers to that here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103920/30851

Comment: Using `xargs -P` is probably the simplest method.  But, why 300?  Does your system have 300 CPU cores/threads?  If not, you probably want to limit it an maximum of 1 background job per core....and since `mkvmerge` is an I/O intensive process, you will want to run significantly less than that in parallel, otherwise they'll all be fighting each other for disk I/O.  Also, if you have more than one drive, it's a good idea to write the output file to a separate drive so that reads aren't contending with writes for I/O.

Comment: how would you use xargs -P with my script? The files are read and written into a network storage mount so there is no I/O and I have fast networks

Comment: Pipe a list of filenames (preferably NUL-separated, e.g. from `find ... -print0`) into `xargs -0 -r -P`, which runs a script that iterates over the filename args and runs `mkvmerge` on them.   BTW, there **is** I/O happening, it's just happening on a remote file server....and even the fastest of networks would struggle, at best, to keep up with the I/O performance of a local disk, especially if it's an SSD or ramdisk.   Quite often it's better/faster to write to a temporary dir on a fast local fs, then `mv` the file to its final location when finished.