# Problem in writing a parallel version of my Bash code

Tags: bash, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I am trying to parallelise my sample Bash script and have tried commands like `&` and `wait`. Please let me know what is an effective way to make it parallel

My current code is working fine for limited entries in the reg2 variable. But I have millions of entries in the reg2 variable. So I want to make my outermost loop parallel. To get the same output i.e., 0,1,2,:,3,4,:,5,6, after parallelizing the code

```
#!/bin/bash

# array1=$1
# array2=($2)
# reg2=($3)

array1=('bam1' 'bam2' 'bam3' 'bam4' 'bam5' 'bam6' 'bam7')
array2=('cell1' 'cell1' 'cell1' 'cell2' 'cell2' 'cell3' 'cell3')
reg2=('chr1:10484-10572' 'chr1:10589-10632' 'chr1:10636-10661' 'chr1:10665-10690' 'chr1:10694-10719') 

start=`date +%s.%N`

l=${#reg2[@]} # number of regions is 30 million on real data
reg_cov=()
j=0
for r in ${reg2[@]}; do
    
    (cov_array=()
    old_array2_element=${array2[0]}
    
    for i in ${!array1[*]}; do
      new_array2_element=${array2[$i]}
      
      if [[ "$new_array2_element" != "$old_array2_element" ]]; then
        cov_array+=(":")
        old_array2_element=$new_array2_element
      fi
      cov_array+=($i) # in actual code this step takes 4-5 seconds to process
      sleep 2
    done
    
    
    reg_cov+=($(IFS=, ; echo "${cov_array[*]}"))  )
    wait
    
    ((j++)) 
    echo "$j/$l"
done

#echo ${reg_cov[@]}
cov=()
cov+=(${reg_cov[@]})
echo $cov


end=`date +%s.%N`; runtime=$( echo "$end - $start" | bc -l ); runtime=${runtime%.*}; hours=$((runtime / 3600)); minutes=$(( (runtime % 3600) / 60 )); seconds=$(( (runtime % 3600) % 60 ))
echo "==> completed Runtime: $hours:$minutes:$seconds (hh:mm:ss)"
```

Comment: The important part is to explain - in your question - what you are trying to achieve, why you want to parallelise it, and how your code currently works

Comment: my current code is working fine for limited entries in the reg2 variable. But I have millions of entries in reg2 variable. So I want to make my outermost loop parallel. To get the same output

Comment: Please explain _in your question_. Put everything in the one place so you make it easy for people to help you

Comment: "_To get the same output_" - what output?

Comment: "But I have millions of entries" sounds like one of the cases where you should strongly consider using some other language/environment.

Comment: @ChrisDavies You can just run the script by pasting it on the terminal. In my actual code output is something like that.

Comment: re: *`millions of entries in the reg2`* and *`# number of regions is 30 million on real data`* ... where does the data in `reg2` come from? for 30 million entries I'm guessing the data is coming from one or more files in which case your code should probably rethink your design and consider reading directly from the file(s); side question: have you verified you can actually store 30 million entries in `reg2`? assuming 20 characters per position you're talking about 600 MB of data (plus the array overhead); regardless ....

Comment: using a `bash` loop to process 30 million entries is going to be painfully slow and require an excessive amount of cpu resources; while parallelizing the process sounds good, even an 8-way parallel operation will be slow *and* it'll peg 8 of your cores/threads at 100% cpu utilization (I hope you've got a good cooling solution for your processor); without a detailed (textual) description of what you're doing, I'm guessing a rewrite in `awk`, `perl`, `ruby`, etc is going to be quite a bit faster (and possibly without the need for parallelization)

Comment: if you're worried about this taking so long to run then why have you added a `sleep 2` in the inner `for` loop? for this small sample you're running `sleep 2` a total of 35 times, ie, adding 70 secs to the total run time; are you really planning on running `sleep 2` for, what, 300 million * length(array1) times?

Comment: Are you processing millions of lines one by one in a loop in bash? This is extremely inefficient as at the very least every line will need to create multiple external processes. Depending on what you need to do, use `awk`, `perl` or `python` to do the job far faster.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, with millions of items, you probably should use pretty much anything other than Bash, exactly due to performance reasons. Shells usually aren't very fast, and Bash is among the slowest. I wouldn't expect it to be very efficient in working with a huge array either, but I don't think I've seen tests on that in particular.

Your script also starts two subshells per each iteration of the outer loop, one starting at `(cov_array=()` and the other in the command substitution `$(IFS=, ; echo "${cov_array[*]}")`. In Bash, those will involve forking a child process, which isn't that bad if done in moderation, but repeated millions of times, it'll start to cost something.

Then again, if each item takes 4-5 seconds to process, the overhead of a child process might not matter that much. (You'll also take about 10 days for 3 M entries with 16x parallelization just for those couple of seconds per item. Or is it 4-5 seconds per *inner* loop iteration? So, that time multiplied by the number of items in `array1`. With 7 items there as above, that'd be something like the beginning of March. You might want to consider if the innermost step can be optimized.)

Also note that as it stands, your script doesn't print anything useful: the assignment to `reg_cov` is in a subshell, so it won't be visible to the main program in the end, and there will be no output. Running multiple tasks in parallel will also require running several distinct processes, and you'd have to make arrangements to move the results back to the main process, if that's what you need. It won't happen automatically, at least not in the shell. Or just read from files and print to a file.

Then there are the relatively minor issues that `${reg2[@]}` will have the array elements undergo word splitting: you should use `"${reg2[@]}"` instead. Also `for i in ${!array1[*]}` looks a bit odd as you're not actually using `array1` anywhere: it seems to me you could just loop over the values of `array2` directly instead. And `echo $cov` only prints the element at index `0` of `cov`, to print the whole array, you'd need `echo "${cov[@]}"` or `echo "${cov[*]}"` to print the whole thing.

---

Depending on what the innermost step of your task actually does, and where the items of `reg2` come from, I'd suggest looking at e.g. GNU Parallel. It can read input from files, run a process for each item, and collect the output in a sensible order.

---

That said, if you want to parallelize something in the shell, there are some solutions in earlier posts, see e.g.  [Parallelize a Bash FOR Loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103920/170373)

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to see what you want to do, but let us assume you have a file with 30 million lines called `reg2.txt`, and for each line you want to run a bash function:

```
doit() {
  reg2="$1"
  echo do stuff with "$reg2"
  array1=('bam1' 'bam2' 'bam3' 'bam4' 'bam5' 'bam6' 'bam7')
  for i in ${!array1[*]}; do
     printf "$i "
  done
  echo
}
```

You should make sure `doit chr1:10484-10572` does the correct thing.

When that is working, you can do:

```
export -f doit
cat reg2.txt | parallel doit
```

This will run `doit` for each line in reg2.txt running 1 job per CPU thread in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the outer loop has ~30 million iterations, the inner loop ~7, and the innermost calculation take 4-5 seconds. Together that would take 29.9 years to complete !
Parallelizing this approach, across say 64 cores might, in the best case reduce the execution time to ~5.6 months, which is still impractical.

The best approach is to first optimize the code of the 4-5 second calculation (not shown).